# CakePHP: Setting default value on a select with optgroups

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

On a normal select, with no optgroups, the following code in CakePHP would make a value the default one:

> 'selected' => $value

Once I have optgroups (a select tag with headings) how do I set a default value? The previous code doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you might try it like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('group_id', array('type'=>'select','default'=>'2'));
```

leading to the following HTML being generated:

```
<option value="2" selected="selected">Managers</option>
```

Now option two is shown instead any other one.

Answer (score 5):

dont use "value" or "selected" etc. this will break your forms in POST.
if you must use the view level, use "default".

a better way is to set them from the controller:

```
if ($this->RequestHandler->is('post')) {
    ...
} else {
    $this->data['Model']['field'] = 2; // e.g.
}
```

see http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/ for details

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $this->Form->input('point', array(
    'label'=>'',
    'options'=>$list_of_options,
    'value'=>$default_value,
    'empty'=>'--select--', 
    'onchange'=>'some_action();' 
  )
);
```

Comment: Thank you for this `'empty'=>'--select--'`, you saved my day!